# Mass Change to Letters in Microsoft Word 2003

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a folder of around 1000 letters in Microsoft Word 2003.

These letters have a header with a similar layout but the content can differ. The layout of the header is a 2 column 2 row table but with the 2nd column having the cells merged. There are always two carriage returns just before the header table.

I need to go into each letter and delete the content of the 1st column & 1st Cell and the contents of the 2nd Column, replacing it with nothing.

Comment: You can write a VBA macro to do the things you mention. However, if you have no previous experience of VBA programming, it might be as easy to do it by hand if it's only this one time.

Comment: If you still want to try it the VBA way, look up the different things you need to do here on SO or on the internet: find all the files, open them, edit and save.

Comment: Or, you can just wait and someone will write it for you! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all files using a VBA macro and apply the changes to the table, e.g. using the following code:

```
Sub CleanHeader()
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim strFile As String

    strDirectory = "C:\tmp\"
    strFile = Dir(strDirectory & "*.doc")

    Do While strFile <> ""
        Dim oDoc As Document
        Dim oTable As Table

        Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strDirectory & strFile)
        Set oTable = oDoc.Tables(1) ' get the correct table here
        oTable.Columns(1).Delete ' deletes an entire column
        oTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.text = "" ' empties a cell

        oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```